# How to add a page break on jsPDF in react app?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

When generating PDFs using the jspdf library, my pictures are cut. Everything is fine with the text, it is transferred to another page, but the pictures are cut. I can't find a solution anywhere, can you help?

[image]

autoPaging: 'text' not helped